# String is not a subtype of Map<String, dynamic> in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

im using this json response to convert it to an object

*json response*

```
{"Data":"{\"IdToken\":\"eyJraWQiOiJxazZwYk9GZVdPWnRTbWorczlqMng2cDN5bUFUcXdDTlhMQ09Ic1JIOFNFPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.lP2Uy902c1KW6o3IS_im3pLsvcpHg74EelmFsSbgDMNA3npLxAqE9670k0Dwx6uoADx0B5JxR51RiOS3-hs3fVyDJsjrqJmeTSpw5JQBYgCZpEukPeLtH-Mc9J_71zt4a3we8SAHoPuwLWHM8W4y6GILmQMzIbuXkalQvd1XSopWo-ml1G7VCBmLBmy3vanUUmD50nl8vYrLLG2ubzLO9588e2ldhtJHrj6P-qhAb3UiQMvD5gTuiYuhiXsdI9ukmiN9Ik3Drqs0pG1lW0Imqc1RcTsli_CJwXyFCvDKBsKNpd17DhzmrEW9l29pHHEc8aVNWpcY7L3zfxlO9AnmZw\",\"AccessToken\":\"eyJraWQiOiJrVkJER2laeWNmd0dIaVZPMHV4aEY4eDNTRzJldlpSbnNBbTZVcHBBQkowPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.FJVD429PTgl5YFSUH7W3CPBPlLmE7x97lIj0PmvYWIn7p2zQwVjjZMUGX9dcaH3DUH6hNiArRmT20J3o3QkKzrd0Knmoh3khAY2HvDqQr2UA-YXIaHevmAEPvBrnGlIu5Xo4HttQxDhayxazl7DnetEG1J1vpM3TEaXPUTMNpgslp9NUMpRMC_VjfEHwuBIDKeo76VgUeJN7bW8lb6Mzna8c8C3tXmnQ0mUjrxkZKlVaFb3FuqHh06wryVk0q0l2WOnO7a1mheLiPY5uxe2dItUsRk-fivHEem86a2sqF0m0MvKmtFgfW91Z_tEHiyIogPD3UG7JiLcLEQmeeL2_4Q\",\"RefreshToken\":\"eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.zEzMEGsXKtmIMcQ6xTA0J1rznfXZIu-Vpj5UtxOFWag_f3HFDaXVo57zsTBHzDmKgp3kMISpDtuHsiB3639G0jSE-eaPoMfRZHbhabBddL2xIB3Ho021CNMqPZp8PKEfGo0fqO9-rPliRMJvagTLHA-qitfyMwpz5WfSjc6q59Saa727xNTsARqWXYAr3fZUUQr-hZaU8EGNTyzME36JoTlfq6kTQ_0jtDGWCN4kuY88Q9X-4wjiIIBiL3sMIOiy4V-2JD2uD-6vc50cttXQ8l9vSANdBfcLkEW6qwDF_GG5r_-i9c6qfpJrB289zDXMCuqK6MiaIC7lP7koxo_cNQ.ULCqvoRl2xlJ9yd4.MVHmpHEAHOmwVgCXBdBMMAnOQtw0TJP9CDPzvNNs6dt1XwfUxq-Sc72PdxTx14KY6KoBV_3-Z2BzAr-y4CVccnkLAwGhxYRPEXYhv4BsmPawg5nEmLKrQ-N3_lNxLwyJ__QStTwXjuFgfjy0hMNioRJPIsTBwHmIOP3xQsw1otPxxp7Oeu67ppuOB47y-BaVfgpLrH59Qu6QhlgHa2E2AGE7d2ZbfwuLqlsUkj6ry4xelOtSGW-fCzMrjmxgmSvdWrnnUTG_7TS8xLQSfvm5p29wbuH-TxZ--z7wVjr9Hl2UoJeIxs0MZPBHLfw8DodMQWHHKkKj8c6zzE7sIznt4UD4BwguvYahgZ79QQd9XRzuK3lCN8sLqHpPNLLl3lcDuxsNABYzGUnDBwt6xHGjJTDed76Jx4_ZuPr2u4FE5RNxCAYGACI9D1c0pns2z4CoIeC-9AoHVqd78jm73ePJwQ-nFzLTa_IhhrDc44pVcFQ383QxaLasJqnpwDPpoVbjVpEEgM676RUDwowrpPXNKY9FOg1wgQAJTOR6Nm6bGE5tvVQhKnppOSDtX6uYLCLwhK66B2FIq0SgHJn-3CmiL0p6_SRGhHYhcZ09VdvieUDb5DhGWTxDJICjpdmU7ma6IdoqLfbfD_vzeKpVWIfx8yELiRjZw_cedZ89KBL0AlX_gg15ccs7dWp3_k8j9ZAJuOjp-aEarsrhSqGBBMFqg6GFAvSQvCQq3UjC7AFWpvBftuZY6SjF5XeFQFdRfyTZ-3G1ToKUYS7gniMxhT9lmgDp7uU5oPLlPE8O5d2PcgrbekajO1nOq4-obQZhFYTNQbV6V76ktq8ydW6icX-iyJM2nvRSPxvDcm0L5Z8c4Pl7_uJAZfck-28rL0-FRW-TwD16nkM4SYn961GUpqwbvIA6AdBU2aGrJGIioeXcnAAMVshejWhhn710Qq4A0--HJdmsywGnRSonUfO56cqP0kQNDgoh35HIDedjguzZAOYyFdflYo4jR8QjbgYYZSv7oLliZKI-6DwfEhJRuYIdVMIt7zTdNpaEnUOIPuhziF67zkAgXvwaQhDK4oP_b4jRXdJ1j2lKeSeJbE5CuQ8TrMbb8YEHHZ0FCTX61PJVEtEOgBhgINClgF2-2gmzcEVylftv3ap56BNV76r7cEnUeIEQnhi1x6emtCzUyci-5j6KIyXZGstuM-5zPod5y47RXKxyP8w7PxQX0mBrNSpU_Lkw0H37RuQTbWnuTMagtGeYj3z33poSVpYTOCUs7RAyg3eVMNMDJWuH598Sew5Vf7nK.cYy20EQngV7xyTsUBWHy0g\"}","Name":null,"Message":null,"WaitInSeconds":0,"Success":true,"Errors":[],"ErrorNumber":0}
```

*model class*

```
import 'dart:convert';

JwtTokenResponseModel jwtTokenResponseModelFromJson(String str) =>
    JwtTokenResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String jwtTokenResponseModelToJson(JwtTokenResponseModel data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class JwtTokenResponseModel {
  JwtTokenResponseModel({
    this.data,
    this.name,
    this.message,
    this.waitInSeconds,
    this.success,
    this.errors,
    this.errorNumber,
  });

  Data? data;
  String? name;
  String? message;
  int? waitInSeconds;
  bool? success;
  List<dynamic>? errors;
  int? errorNumber;

  factory JwtTokenResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      JwtTokenResponseModel(
        data: Data.fromJson(json["Data"]),
        name: json["Name"],
        message: json["Message"],
        waitInSeconds: json["WaitInSeconds"],
        success: json["Success"],
        errors: List<dynamic>.from(json["Errors"].map((x) => x)),
        errorNumber: json["ErrorNumber"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Data": data!.toJson(),
        "Name": name,
        "Message": message,
        "WaitInSeconds": waitInSeconds,
        "Success": success,
        "Errors": List<dynamic>.from(errors!.map((x) => x)),
        "ErrorNumber": errorNumber,
      };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return toJson().toString();
  }
}

class Data {
  Data({
    this.idToken,
    this.accessToken,
    this.refreshToken,
  });

  String? idToken;
  String? accessToken;
  String? refreshToken;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        idToken: json["IdToken"],
        accessToken: json["AccessToken"],
        refreshToken: json["RefreshToken"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "IdToken": idToken,
        "AccessToken": accessToken,
        "RefreshToken": refreshToken,
      };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return toJson().toString();
  }
}
```

When calling the converter here

final converted = json.decode(res);
return JwtTokenResponseModel.fromJson(converted);

I get the error String is not a subtype of Map<String, dynamic>.
how can I rectify this error.
any help is welcome heartedly.

Answer (score 0):

this line causes the error I might say " data: Data.fromJson(json["Data"]),"

replace it by Data.fromJson( json.decode(json["Data"]))

to check if it's really the line causes the issue print it a see if it's a string or map